# OneDrive FilePicker works with a personal account, but not with business account

Tags: onedrive

I have an Angular web app that opens a OneDrive FilePicker and uses a Google Firebase cloud function to transfer the files the user picks to Google storage. It works fine if I use a personal OneDrive account, but if it is a business account I get a CORS error and the files are not transferred. My client-side code looks like this:

```
oneDriveOptions = {
    clientId: '#####',
    action: 'download',
    multiSelect: true,
    advanced: {
        redirectUri: `${Utils.getBaseURL()}/one-drive-redirect`,
    },
    success: (files: any[]) => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
            this.oneDriveCallback(files);
        });
    },
    cancel: () => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
            this.dbService.indeterminateProgress = false;
        });
    },
    error: () => {
        this.zone.run((error) => {
            this.dbService.indeterminateProgress = false;
            console.error('OneDrive file picker error:', error);
        });
    },
};

async oneDriveClicked() {
    OneDrive.open(this.oneDriveOptions);
    this.dialogRef.close();
}

async oneDriveCallback(files: any) {
    try {
        this.dbService.indeterminateProgress = true;
        const cloudServiceFiles = this.convertOneDriveFiles(files.value);
        await this.dbService.addFromCloudService(this.data.dbData, files.accessToken, cloudServiceFiles, this.data.insertIdx, 'oneDrive');
        this.dbService.indeterminateProgress = false;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        this.dbService.indeterminateProgress = false;
    }
}
```

And on the client side:

```
const getOneDriveFile = async (cloudServiceFile: CloudServiceFile) => {
    const fileStream = oneDriveApi.items.download({
        accessToken: cloudServiceAuthToken,
        itemId: cloudServiceFile.id,
        // drive:,  default: 'me'. If it's set to be either 'user'/'drive'/'group'/'site', driveId has to be set to.
        // driveId: The id of the drive that was shared to us. Must be set if params.drive is set.
    });
    return fileStream;
};
```

The output I get in the console:
[image]

Any suggestion why this code works fine for a personal account but gives CORS error from a business account?

Answer (score 0):

This means you didn't register your app in Microsoft system so that they didn't let you to use the one drive .
follow this steps then check your app again

Setting up
To get started you need to register your application and receive an app ID from the Azure App registrations page.

To get started you need to register your application and receive an app ID from the Azure App registrations page.

1. Log in to the Azure App registrations page using your Microsoft account, or a work or school account.
2. Click Add an app and enter a name for your app.
3. After your application is created, configure it to support the JavaScript picker:
4. Click Generate New Password to create an Application secret. While this value is not necessary for the picker, it must have been created.
5. Click Add Platform and then select Web.
6. Enter one or more URLs where the picker will be hosted on your website. Each page that hosts the picker needs to have a redirect URL provided.
7. Click the Save button to save your changes.
8. Copy the Application Id for your application and use it in the JavaScript options object you provided to open or save a file.

Comment: I have done that and that makes it work with the OneDrive File Picker. But if the account is OneDrive business it stil doesn't work. I think it has to do with I also need to have my account verified by becoming a MPN member. I tried that, but in Legal Info I don't get past Employment Verification. The only help Microsoft offers on this is to write to support and I have done that, but never received an answer. Some help would really be appriciated.

Comment: well that means you need to communicate to Microsoft no one else can help you.